# Accessing current_user in Rails engine application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rails-engines

I created a Rails engine to log some activities in my app. Everything is ok at the model and view level, tests are passing and views are visible in the host app. Now for controllers... I just can't access the host, main ApplicationController to insert a before_filter inside of it.

My app/controllers directory inside the engine looks like this:

```
/app
  /controllers
    /storyteller
      /application_controller.rb
```

Then, inside of application_controller.rb I added this:

```
module Storyteller
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController 

    before_action :save_current_user

    def save_current_user
      raise current_user.inspect # Doesn't raise
    end
  end
end

raise 'here' # No, doesn't raise anything too!
```

Doing so... nothing happens, it even looks like this file is not loaded at all. I read tons of tutorials and docs, but never had it to work.

All I want to do is to track current_user everywhere, on every action/route of the host app, What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

the controller should inherit `ActionController::Base`

e.g.

`module Storyteller
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Put your code here
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

try the `include` block to declare your `before_action`

e.g.

```
module Storyteller
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    included do
      before_action :save_current_user
    end

    def save_current_user
      raise current_user.inspect # Doesn't raise
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Even if I throw a big raise at the beginning of the file, it doesn't raise nothing. Looks like this file is not even loaded at all. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! Got it working by studying some other Gems on github... here's how I did it for the controller:

```
# Engine /app/controllers/storyteller/application_controller.rb
module Storyteller
  module ApplicationController 
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
      before_action :save_current_user

      def save_current_user
        UserRegistry.current_user ||= current_user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I also had to add this to engine setup:

```
# /lib/storyteller/engine.rb
module Storyteller
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Storyteller

    initializer "get into controllers" do |app|
      ActionController::Base.send :include, Storyteller::ApplicationController
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this could help someone...